# How do I weight inputs to a regression model so that one figures into the model more than the other?

Tags: data-mining, least-squares, text-mining, weighted-regression

I have obtained a series of weights from a text mining algorithm. Unfortunately, my algorithm is not capable of doing certain tasks that are too similar without some sort of regression analysis, say auditing. Also, unfortunately, I took the basic statistics for engineers course which covered certain topics in least squares and regression and how to compute them in a matrix but did not go over weighting.

Is there a way I can weight the output of the text mining algorithm more in the regression than the other vector components when calculating the regression models coefficients?

Comment: Did you look at weighted least squares?

Comment: I am pretty new to calculating least squares outside of the basic equation I learned in class. Is there an optimal weighting scheme for weighted least squares?

Comment: You say you already have weights ... why would you seek optimal weights is weights are given?

Comment: I did some more reading after work. Thanks. I see that 1/(sd^2) will do the trick.